# Will a heap allocated object get deleted when I assign it to a vector and then delete the vector?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, heap-memory

I'm new to computer science and I want to know if an object is being deleted if I heap allocate it and then for e. put it in a vector of pointer and then delete the vector. Will the heap object be gone? Here is an example of what I mean.

```
int main()
{
   Type* someHeapObject = new Type();
   
   vector<Type*> someVector(0);

   someVector.push_back(someHeapObject);
}
```

So here's the main part: Can I delete the heap object with `delete someVector[0]`, and then I DON'T have to delete it anymore like this: `delete someHeapObject`

Comment: You don't have to delete it. In fact you should not, because you cannot delete it twice. The pattern you are using is dangerous. You create two pointers to the same memory, then you delete one, leaving the other pointer (in this case the vector) containing the pointer. If someone tried to access that pointer from the vector, it would then crash. If you delete a pointer, NULL it out. If you hold multiple copies, NULL them all out, or erase the entry from the vector.

Comment: First of all, `delete [] someVector` will undefined behavior.

Comment: `delete someVector[0]` has the same effect in your code snippet as `delete someHeapObject`.    Any object created with a `new` expression must be released exactly ONCE with a corresponding `delete` expression (never `delete`ing at all gives a leak, `delete`ing more than once gives undefined behaviour).   Hence, if you `delete someVector[0]` you CANNOT do `delete someHeapObject` (the reverse is also true) without producing undefined behaviour (unless, of course, `someHeapObject` has been reassigned to the result of another `new` expression).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things that you have to take care of:

##### Mistake 1

In `delete [] someVector` you're using the `delete []` form when you should be using the `delete` form because you used the `new` form and not the `new[]` form for allocating memory dynamically. That is, `delete [] someVector` is undefined behavior.

##### Mistake 2

The second thing that you must take care of is that **you should not use two or more consecutive `delete`'s on the same pointer**.

Now, when you wrote:

```
someVector.push_back(someHeapObject);
```

a copy of the pointer `someHeapObject` is added to the vector `someVector`. This means that now there are 2 pointers pointing to the same dynamically allocated memory. One pointer is the `someHeapObject` and the second is the one inside the vector.

And as i said, now you should only use `delete` on only one of the pointers. For example you can write:

```
delete someHeapOjbect; //now the memory has been freed 

//YOU CAN'T USE delete someVector[0] anymore
```

Or you can write:

```
delete someVector[0]; //now te memory has been freed

//YOU CAN'T USE delete someHeapObject[0] anymore
```

---

Note that better option would be to use smart pointers instead explicitly doing memory management using `new` and `delete`.

Comment: Hi thank your very much my english is not so good im glad u understood my question, you answered it completly